# Validate model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an issue regarding validating my model, depending on which text fields have a value. I have a simple model:

```
    public class Person
    {
        [DisplayName("Forename")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a forename")]
        public string Forename { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Surname")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Country")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Phone Number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a phone number")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Mobile Number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a mobile number")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
    }
```

In my view I display Forename, Surname, Country & Phone as text fields using the following code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Forename)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Forename)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Forename)
```

If a user doesn't have a phone number, they click on a button and this reveals another text field for Mobile number. The "Phone" text field then gets reset. If the user enters a mobile number and then submits the form it fails. Is it possible to have a conditional statement in my model validation to only validate a property if another property doesn't have a value.

So if "Mobile" has a value, but "Phone" doesn't, validation will validate "Mobile" but ignore "Phone" and vice versa. Apologies if the last paragraph wasn't clear enough. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could have the model implement IValidatableObject and do your more complex validation there.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do the validation in the controller, Pseudo-code below

```
if (Condition)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyNameHere", "ErrorMessageHere");
}
```

Keep your view exactly as it is. Just remove the [Required()] tag from your model. You also want to add this code above the if (ModelState.IsValid) code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually with a simple check like:

```
if (ModelState.ContainsKey("Phone Number") && !ModelState.ContainsKey("Mobile Number"))
         ModelState.Remove("Phone Number");
else if (!ModelState.ContainsKey("Phone Number") && ModelState.ContainsKey("Mobile Number"))
         ModelState.Remove("Mobile Number");
```

Comment: Since OP is using client side validation, it fails on the client and never gets this far.